# Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему будут игнорироваться width и right?

Tags: css, html5

"Одновременно указанные свойства left и right формируют ширину элемента, но только если width не указано. Стоит добавить свойство width и значение right будет проигнорировано. Аналогично произойдёт и с высотой элемента, но уже участвуют свойства top, bottom и height".
Источник: https://webref.ru/course/position/absolute#content

Comment: Width вообще игнорироваться не будет. И right не очень-то будет игнорироваться, там margin-left и margin-right пересчитаются, если хотя бы один из них auto. Либо проигнорируется margin-right впрочем, можно считать, что и right тоже.

Comment: То есть в источнике ошибка?

Comment: Нет, там такого не написано.